# Are there any thin/precise styluses that are compatible with the Droid X?

Tags: motorola-droid-x, touchscreen, drawing, stylus

I'd like to write formulas and notes on my Droid X. All the styluses that I found have a thick end and don't simulate a pen, it's more like a finger. Does anyone know of any styluses with thinner or more accurate tips? Do pens from tablets like Lenovo work?

Comment: You may want to separate the wacom pad question into its own question. Users don't know you have that question just by reading the title to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thin styluses are usually for resistive screens, they don't work with Droid X's capacitive screen.

[The difference between capacitive and resistive touchscreens](http://quezi.com/3994)

Answer (score 2):

I have a [Pogo Stylus](http://tenonedesign.com/stylus.php) which was originally meant for the iphone although I see they have an Android version now.  It works ok, but I feel like I have to push down harder than I want to to get it to work.  **It is accurate**, more so than my finger, however if I don't maintain enough pressure when drawing a line for example, there will be gaps in the line.  I have a screen protector on and I've never tried it on the naked screen so this might be a factor.  When all is said and done I don't use it very much so I can't provide a detailed review.

If you don't want to spend the money there are a number DIY capacitive tutorials that look pretty good.  Some mimic the pogo design and others don't.  Here are a few:

- [Pogo like 1](http://lifehacker.com/5532481/turn-a-cheap-pen-into-a-touchscreen-stylus)
- [Pogo like 2](http://lifehacker.com/5550029/diy-touch+screen-stylus-new-and-improved)
- [With a sock](http://www.instructables.com/id/Soft-iPhone-and-iPad-Stylus/)
- [With a piece of anti-static bag](http://lifehacker.com/5480040/make-a-diy-touchscreen-stylus-from-anti+static-bags)
- [With an energy bar wrapper](http://lifehacker.com/5647115/make-a-tablet-stylus-out-of-a-candy-wrapper) and a drunk puppet

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing someone do tests on the accuracy of capacitive screens and in reality, they're terribly inaccurate. Unlike resistive screens, a stylus won't make much difference for you. I believe it was said that a fine stylus would provide just as much accuracy as using a hot dog.