# Is the Motorola Xoom tablet suitable for making notes on pdf?

Tags: applications, pdf, motorola-xoom, stylus

I am considering buying a Motorola Xoom to get rid of piles of notes that I have from uni.

My questions are:

- Does the Xoom have a digitizer pen (or can you buy a compatible one)?
- Does Android have an app to make notes on pdf files?

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Xoom has a "capacitive" touch screen (as do most modern multi-touch compatible devices) most stylus pens are designed for the older "resistive" touch screens and won't do anything on a capacitive screen. See this previous question on suitable styluses for a capacitive screen http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/

Comment: See also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14164/how-can-i-write-in-a-pdf-with-a-tablet-and-a-pen-a-k-a-is-there-a-xournal-alte

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there are any Android applications that will allow you to make notes on PDF files. You might be better off looking towards a Windows capable tablet, since you would be able to run Acrobat on that.

Comment: In fact, there are at least two apps now, that allow you to make notes in PDF files: [RepliGo Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cerience.reader.app) and [ezPDF Reader](https://market.android.com/details?id=udk.android.reader)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the xoom can be used with a pen, it wasnt designed for that, i have a xoom and all i use it for is browsing the internet and playing games, it could be a very useful tool for taking notes and such with the onscreen keyboard and i think it is very handy to have. It has a ton of hard drive space and if you download a good app that lets you take notes then i think it would be good for you, if you dont like typing your notes and you want to actually write them then i dont think the xoom is good for that. you could try using a pen with it but it could scratch the screen, you could ask someone at an at&t or verison store if they would recommend a tablet that suits your needs.