# How can I add and edit bookmarks within a PDF on Android?

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I use my Android tablet to read long PDF files.
**How can I add and edit bookmarks within a PDF on Android?**

Comment: "Is there a App that does X?" questions are off-topic here. I rephrased your question so that it fits within your FAQ rules.

Answer (score 5):

Direct editing of PDF content is something hard to achieve. As far as I know, the only solution for this is [Qoppa PDF Notes](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.qoppa.activities.notes). However: bookmarks (create & edit) and annotations (also create & edit) are possible.

The best eBook-Reader on Android, also known as [Moon+ Reader Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flyersoft.moonreaderp), supports this not only for PDF (Pro only!) -- but also for EPUB and other formats (Pro & Free). Another popular solution (PDF only) is [ezPDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader).

For more solutions, you might consult the Playstore, and check with the descriptions. The keywords are "bookmark" and "annotation".

Another Q&A here which might prove interesting to you is: [Is there any software for Tablets to edit PDF or PS -files?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19250/is-there-any-software-for-tablets-to-edit-pdf-or-ps-files)

Comment: Oops -- there *IS* at least one editor available, I almost forgot. Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: The Kindle App also supports this, I believe.

Comment: You don't need a pdf editor to set bookmarks silly, just any old pdf viewer should have the ability to bookmark a page.

Comment: @mchid Do you see any PDF *editor* mentioned in my answer? I don't. So what are you referring to? ;)

Comment: So what? Those are remarks, not the core of the answer. No need to call me "silly" for that ;)

Comment: @mchid that was unintentional. But too late now :) So maybe we clean up the mess altogether (especially the silly ones ;)?

Answer (score 1):

To edit existing bookmarks:

If you are using Adobe reader, tap the screen and the tap the icon down on the lower right that looks like an open book.

Then, tap the "bookmarks" tab.

Press and hold on the bookmark you wish to edit. You will be given the option to edit the name of the bookmark.

To add a new bookmark:

Tap the screen when you are on the page you wish to bookmark.

Then, tap the bookmark icon on the top near the right. This icon is flat at the top and is more tall than it is long. The bottom of the icon is like a Chevron or upside down v.

To access your bookmarks:

Tap the screen and then tap the icon down on the lower right hand side that looks like an open book.

Then, tap the "bookmarks" tab.

Tap the desired bookmarked page or edited bookmark title to view.

---

Alternatively if you are using WPS:

tap the screen when viewing a pdf document and select the view tab on the bottom right of the screen.

Bookmarks are on the left (you may need to scroll down a bit). There is an add bookmark icon on the far left and there is a bookmarks icon that will list existing bookmarked pages that you can select.

The bookmark function in both of these viewers is a lifesaver when doing math homework to skip to the answers for odd numbered problems in the back or at the the end pages of the textbook file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Xodo pdf reader and editor. It is free with unbelievable features, no ads and you can find it in google play.