# Android software to write on anything?

Tags: screen-sharing

I currently do not own a smartphone or a tablet, but am interested in getting one or both that could help me with the following:

I am a teacher. I regularly have notes displayed on an overhead projector *AND* simultaneously write on a chalkboard. I would like to be able to write (using a stylus) directly onto the screen on top of what I am displaying.

I usually display notes in PDF or Powerpoint. If it would be possible to then save the written notes on the file would be a major plus, though not necessary.

Is this possible with Android devices – and if so, how could it be done?

Comment: you can try with team viewer connection on your tab to other devices

Comment: To close-voters: This question seems perfectly fine (after a little re-phrasing I've just applied, at least). Remember there are features like screen mirroring, which might even be pre-installed.

Comment: Izzy's answer is (as typical of Izzy) fantastic. I'll just break form a bit and insert my own experience with tablets in the classroom: Android tablets for projection are a great idea in theory, but have been a pain in practice. The best results I had for doing real-time annotation and various projection tasks were (disappointingly, considering how I'm a big Android fan) with x86 Windows (Non-RT) tablets. Combining Miracast with generally excellent app and stylus support makes a winning device in the classroom - but expensive.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitly possible. There are even multiple approaches I could think of:

- **Screen mirroring**
  Some devices already ship with this functionality. My sister e.g. just got her new *Samsung Galaxy S4 mini* which I helped her to set up, and I noted a related "toggle" in the notification bar to switch "mirroring" on/off. Also, newer builds of the custom ROM [cyanogenmod](/questions/tagged/cyanogenmod) IMHO offer this feature. Especially via HDMI, this also should be supported (maybe requiring an additional app).
- **Remote Tools**
  *iDev* already mentioned *Team Viewer* in his comment. While the specific component to remote access the Android device itself only exists for few devices (the list might grow, some time given), there are several similar/comparable solutions, as VNC.
- **Other means**
  There might also exist specific "whiteboard apps", designed for exactly this purpose. I don't know such one (but I didn't explicitly check for), but searching the Playstore cannot hurt (to ease this, as the "official *Google Play* website is quite restricted in its search capabilities since its relaunch, I recommend using [AppBrain](http://www.appbrain.com/) for searching; it's an alternative "web frontend" to Google Play).

Comment: Thank you everyone for the wonderful answers. I've realized two things: 1. I did a poor job of asking the question I was actually thinking and 2. I hadn't thought through the process of connecting a tablet to a projector very well. The question I actually was trying to answer (it turns out) was asked and answered in [this thread](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14164/how-can-i-write-in-a-pdf-with-a-tablet-and-a-pen-a-k-a-is-there-a-xournal-alte). Nonetheless thank you for the answers, I will look into these options as well as the ones in the other thread.

Comment: But you did not only a good job locating that other question, but also to link it by mentioning it in a comment here! That promises a great future for you on our site :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is, if your projector supports wifi connection then any android device will work(phone/tablet) with appropriate application. And to view pdfs + to write on it just use Adobe Reader.

Or, you can just install Droid@screen to do it for you link is [this](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/)

hope this helps. :)